# Can't 301 redirect old urls. All going to home page with the server htaccess coding.

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm doing SEO for a website. I want to redirect all old URLs to new URLs but all old URLs going to the home page. The guy who did the new website added htaccess coding. I can see two htaccess files in the server. One file is htaccess and second file is htaccess- 
Website is not working if I deleted one of them.

This is the first htaccess file coding

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ln=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^chi/area_sta.php http://example.com/%1/news? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ln=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^chi/chi.php http://example.com/%1/contact-us? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is the second htaccess- file coding

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I Know 301 permanent URL redirect but when I put them they just go to the home page. Please help me. Tell me should I do. Thank you very much. Nimz

Comment: No one knows how to solve and help this problem ? If you don't know how please tell me a website to ask help please. I spent more than 30 minutes to submit this problem to this website even. Please help.

Comment: Any help ? No one know this ?